# Google actions giving response- "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again." in transaction flow

Tags: actions-on-google

I have developed an application for google assistant that involves transactions. Once the cart is built and the user authorises the transaction via password, Google is giving back this response- "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again." 
I am attaching a screen shot below, need some help on this.
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dy6J.png)

Thanks.

=====================Fulfilment Code=====================

```
const tempApp = actionssdk({ clientId: CLIENT_ID});

tempApp.intent('actions.intent.TRANSACTION_DECISION', async (conv) => {
console.log('Transaction decision complete');
const arg = conv.arguments.get('TRANSACTION_DECISION_VALUE');
console.log('arg.userDecision==========>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', arg.userDecision);
if (arg && arg.userDecision ==='ORDER_ACCEPTED') {
  const finalOrderId = arg.order.finalOrder.id;
  console.log('finalOrderId===============>>>>>>>>>>>>',finalOrderId);
  let stripeToken = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Base64.decode(arg.order.paymentInfo.googleProvidedPaymentInstrument.instrumentToken)));
  stripeToken = JSON.parse(stripeToken);

  console.log('arg.order.paymentInfo----------------->>>>>>>', stripeToken);

  // await conv.ask('Your transaction is being processed, please wait.');

  const platformSession = await PlatformSession.findOne({psid: conv.body.user.userId}).select('activeSessionId').lean().exec();    
  const chatSession = await ChatSession.findOne({_id:platformSession.activeSessionId}).exec();

  const charge = await createCharge(stripeToken, chatSession);

  conv.channel = 'ga';
  conv.handshake = {
    query: {
      psid: conv.body.user.userId,
      ver: 1.1,
      brandName: BRAND_NAME,
      channel: 'ga',
      platformName: 'ga'
    },
    headers: {
      'user-agent': '',
      origin: '',
      host: '',
    },
  };

  console.log('conv.data********************&&&&&&&&&&&&&***************', conv.data);
  if(charge && charge.id){
   //some code
    conv.ask('Do you want an email confirmation for the booking?');
  }
  else{
    //some code
    conv.ask('Transaction Failed');
  }
} 
else if (arg && arg.userDecision === 'DELIVERY_ADDRESS_UPDATED') {
  conv.ask(new DeliveryAddress({
    addressOptions: {
      reason: 'To know where to send the order',
    },
  }));
} else {
  conv.close('Transaction failed.');
}
```

});

Comment: Good morning, Rafi! When you have a minute, could you update this question with a sample of your fulfillment code?

Comment: Hi, I have added the fulfilment code..please tell me if you can figure out the issue. @MaxWiederholt

Comment: Do you have privacy policy added? Also check Google cloud Assistant logs, there may be something